# Trouble uploading image with InertiaJS, React and Laravel Use FormHelper

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

iam just ask how to change method put to post in FormHelper Inertia js, with reactjs sir ?, because iam using formHelper its not working ? are u have suggest. This my code,

```
const submitHandlerType = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    Inertia.post(route("products.update", model.id), {
        _method: 'put',
        name: data.name,
        category_id: data.category_id,
        descriptions: data.descriptions,
        bestproduct: data.bestproduct,
        image: data.image,

    },{
        onSuccess: () => {reset(), close()},
       }
    )
};
```

its work, but how to doit with formHelper ?

=========================>

```
const { data, setData, post, reset, errors, processing, progress } = useForm({
        name: model.name,
        category_id: model.category_id,
        descriptions: model.descriptions,
        bestproduct: model.bestproduct,
        image: null,
    });


  const submitHandlerType = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        post(route("products.update", model.id), {
            data,
            onSuccess: () => {
                reset(), close();
            },
        });
    };
```

i got null if i die dump in controller with formHelper inertia,
please help me
thanks